# tar command works but takes too long to finish

Tags: linux, unix, tar

I'm using the following command to export a single file called `file` (2.6KB once exported) from `archive.tbz`:

```
tar -xvf archive.tbz ./root/file
```

I see this output a few seconds after running the command

```
x itunes20150701/parental_advisory
```

but the command does not exit for a long time.

When I check the exported file, it looks like it's been fully exported as soon as `x itunes20150701/parental_advisory` has been outputted.

The command will eventually finish, but it's minutes later. What is causing the command to hang for so long, when it seemingly finishes the export of the file itself relatively quickly?

Comment: This is probably better asked on [unix.se]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thank God we can report comments as unkind and not useful ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The `tar` format supports updates. This is done by creating multiple instances of the same file in the archive. Only the latter is the one that should be restored after the extraction ends. `Tar` is therefore looking for all archived files and this is what is taking a long time in your case.

With GNU `tar`, you can select which occurence of the stored files you want to extract. In most cases, there is only one so you can use:

```
tar --occurence=1 -xvf  archive.tbz itunes20150701/parental_advisory
```

Comment: Thanks. Whan can I do for Windows?